# Which programming language do I need to learn for this?

Tags: wordpress

Whenever we add a particular website to Google Search Console, it tells us to confirm the ownership either with the help of an HTML tag or by uploading an HTML file on the server.

So, I have to two questions:

1.) I want to develop a wordpress website which will require a user to confirm the ownership in a similar fashion. Is it possible?

2.) Which Programming Language do I need to know for the same?

P.S: Forgive me if this question is too dumb! :)

Comment: Not necessarily a dumb question, but it is inappropriate for here. This is far too broad and opinion based.

Comment: Where can I get the answers?

Comment: if you want to use WordPress, you need to learn PHP for server side coding. but any language server side can do this, it just take less or more time to make that. and client side, you will always need html and bases of JavaScript

Comment: @calculator120d Try a discussion site like Reddit or Google+.

Comment: @mmm So, according to you, it is possible?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

So if that is the only functionality you are looking for on your site, you wouldn't need a full blown wordpress website.

You could make a webpage that takes a URL (e.g. www.foo.com) and then gets the user to make a file called \itsme.txt.

So your HTML could be as simple as:

```
Enter your website here:  <input type="text" id="website" placeholder="(e.g. www.foo.com)" /><input type="submit" />
```

Then you'd need to learn a little bit of JavaScript (AJAX) to load the file they will place on their website. Something like this:

```
$.ajax("http://www.foo.com/file.txt").done(function(){ 
    /* JS to execute when File exists */ 
}).fail(function(){
    /* JS to execute when File doesn't exist */ 
});
```

If you insist on developing a wordpress website you will need to know a little bit of PHP (since that's what wordpress is built on) - but nowadays you shouldn't need to know a lot of it if you don't mind using templates and widgets.